# Weird output on all rails commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just recently started getting weird output whenever I run any command from the command line within my rails app.  I did just add Devise to it a couple days ago so maybe that's the issue?

One example is this:

```
> rails g mailer UserMailer                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    [16:34:48] (0.1ms)  BEGIN
    User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('')            LIMIT 1
    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
    User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('') LIMIT 1
    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
    create  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
    invoke  haml
    create    app/views/user_mailer
    invoke  rspec
    create    spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb
```

The unexpected output is ALWAYS some sort of SQL logging.  Anyone know what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be uniqueness validation. You have validate_uniqueness_of :email in your model and you are trying to create a new user with the same email, at least the error shows so.

Comment: But I didn't do anything regarding creating users. I ran a "rails generate mailer" command.